# When $40!$ is expressed in base $8$ form, what is the last non–zero digit in the base $8$ expansion?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, factorial

For this problem I have figured out that the number of trailing zeros will be $12$ if the $40!$ will be written in base $8$ but how can we go ahead to find the last non-zero digits after which the trailing zeroes start.

Please help me on this ! I have been stuck at this problem for a while.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I guess you're left with the product of all the odd numbers up to and including 39 and want to know what that comes to $\pmod 8$. I guess if you see what each one of them is $\pmod 8$ you might be able to work it out from there.  I make that $3^5\pmod 8=3$ but I'm terrible at maths so it's just a suggestion. Don't take it as gospel.

Comment: ...Actually, I've assumed $8^{12}$ is the highest power of $2$ that divides your $40!$.  To get your answer you will have to multiply by any remaining powers of $2$ and repeat my modular arithmetic.

Comment: @samerivertwice : can you please explain with a solution? that would be really helpful.

Comment: OK! I got that $40!$ is a multiple of $8^12 \times 2^2 \times \text{Some ODD Number}$ ,right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.  If you're right and it's $2^2$ then divide that out and find out what remains mod $8$.

Comment: Actually I have that wrong. Because it's not $39 \times37\times\ldots$ that remains once you divide out the twos.  You also have the factors $\frac{38}{2}\times\frac{36}{4}\times\ldots$ to multiply too. But you should get the principle now.

Comment: hmmm....can you please put down a solution? I am just getting confused.

Comment: Do you understand that the last digit on the right before the zeroes, is $40!/(8^{12}\times2^2)\pmod 8$?

Answer (score 1):

Count the factors of $2$ in this factorial.  Using the standard formula:

$\lfloor{\frac{40}{2}}\rfloor+\lfloor{\frac{40}{4}}\rfloor+...+\lfloor{\frac{40}{32}}\rfloor=20+10+5+2+1=38$

This is two greater than a multiple of $3$, so the number is $4×\text{ ( an odd number ) }×8^k$ for some whole number $k$.

So the last nonzero digit in base 8 can only be 4.

Comment: Shouldn't $k$ be 12  because we know that highest power of $8$ can be 12 which divides $40!$ ?

Comment: Yes, but the problem did not ask for this count of terminal zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very useful formula for this kind of problems. If $p$ is prime, then the greatest exponent $r$ such that $p^r$ divides $n!$ is
$$r=\sum_{k=1}^{p^k>n}\left\lfloor\frac n{p^k}\right\rfloor$$
So take $p=2$ and $n=40$. Then
$$r=\left\lfloor\frac {40}{2}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac {40}{4}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac {40}{8}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac {40}{16}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac {40}{32}\right\rfloor=20+10+5+2+1=38$$
Since $38=12\cdot 3+2$, the number of trailing zeros is indeed $12$, but $40!/2^{36}$ is still a multiple of $4$ (but not of $8$), so the last nonzero digit is $4$.

Comment: As an aside, in general, this formula is not that useful for this kind of problems, as it would not be sufficient to determine the last nonzero digit. We were lucky that it turned out to be "multiple of 4 but not 8".